# Sending Emails without Intents in Android

Tags: android

I'd like to send a message thru email without using intent. When I press the button, instead of **"*Email was sent successfully*"** is the toast message, it shows "*Email was not sent*" and it doesn't sending the email. Can someone help me regarding this matter?

**MainActivity.java**

```
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email); 
    addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View view) {            

            Mail m = new Mail("gmailusername@gmail.com", "password"); 

                            String[] toArr = {"lp.mar@gmail.com"};
            m.setTo(toArr);  
            m.setFrom("p.mar@gmail.com"); 
            m.setSubject("Email Test"); 
            m.setBody("This is an email sent using my Mail JavaMail wrapper from an Android device."); 

            try { 
            m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

                if(m.send()) { 
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                } else { 
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                } 
            } catch(Exception e) { 
                //Toast.makeText(MailApp.this, "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e); 
            } 
        }
    });
}
```

**Mail.java**

```
public Mail() { 
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server 
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port 
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port 

    _user = ""; // username 
    _pass = ""; // password 
    _from = ""; // email sent from 
    _subject = ""; // email subject 
    _body = ""; // email body 

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off 
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on 

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart(); 

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added. 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
       mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
       mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
       mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
       mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
       mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
  } 

  public Mail(String user, String pass) { 
    this(); 

    _user = user; 
    _pass = pass; 
  } 

  public boolean send() throws Exception { 
    Properties props = _setProperties(); 

    if(_user.equals("") && _pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && _from.equals("") && _subject.equals("") && _body.equals("")) { 
      Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this); 

      MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session); 

      msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from)); 

      InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length]; 
      for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) { 
        addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]); 
      } 
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 

      msg.setSubject(_subject); 
      msg.setSentDate(new Date()); 

      // setup message body 
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      messageBodyPart.setText(_body); 
      _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

      // Put parts in message 
      msg.setContent(_multipart); 

      // send email 
      Transport.send(msg); 

      return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
  } 

  public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
  } 

  @Override 
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass); 
  } 

  private Properties _setProperties() { 
    Properties props = new Properties(); 

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host); 

    if(_debuggable) { 
      props.put("mail.debug", "true"); 
    } 

    if(_auth) { 
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
    } 

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false"); 

    return props; 
  }
```

**Logcat**

```
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081): Could not send email
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:365)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at com.example.emailtest.Mail._setProperties(Mail.java:117)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at com.example.emailtest.Mail.send(Mail.java:72)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at com.example.emailtest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:36)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3558)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14157)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-20 17:01:16.889: E/MailApp(7081):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure that `if` statement in `send()` is correct? It doesn't seem to make sense to try and send off an email if `_user`, `_pass`, `_from`, `_subject` and  `_body` are all empty strings. I'd expect it to be the other way around: they should *not* be empty.

Comment: @MH no I'm not haha! I can't even figure it out if my codes are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this- I had tried it worked for me...

http://androidautomail.blogspot.in/2013/06/auto-generated-mail-from-android.html?m=1

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)